# Circular Winds and Coriolis force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, coriolis-effect

[image]
In northern hemisphere the flow of air is shown which tries to move towards low pressure center but due to Coriolis is deflected as shown.

It's said that this causes a circular anticlockwise flow of air.

How's that?
The air will just try to move in and get deflected as shown and curve away, how then will a circular pattern be formed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the wind reaches a velocity such that the Coriolis and pressure gradient forces balance, it continues at that velocity due to inertia. This state is called geostrophic flow and corresponds to wind along isobars.

For an intense localized low pressure like a hurricane, the flow is not geostrophic—the pressure gradient force is larger in magnitude than the Coriolis force, maintaining the inward net acceleration required for circular motion.

Comment: Thank you got it

Answer (score 1):

The region of low pressure generates a centripetal force. So, the total force in the air elements is the sum of the centripetal and the coriolis.

The result is a rotating movement.

Comment: Thank you got it.